# Generating a mesh from a set of generatively produced co-ordinates

Tags: 3d, 3d-meshes

Using Unity I've been producing sculptural forms that look like this. It's made of patterns of cubes that twist around each other using a flocking algorithm. I'm trying to get it into a 3D printable format.
[image]

From unity I export a PLY that is a list of the co-ords of each cube that looks like:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 17500
property float x
property float y
property float z
end_header
35 2.521441 0
34.72401 -2.06799 4.386663
33.90041 3.202552 8.704146
...
```

Then I've imported that into meshlab and run `Filters > Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction > Surface Reconstruction: Ball Pivoting` with the default parameters.

[image]

This is the result (different iteration so doesn't match top image but similar) which is ok, but obviously not 3d printable.

Is there a better way of doing this in Unity to create a single mesh? I'd be happy with either a single mesh with individual lines or a mesh that makes a single shape as if it were shrink wrapped.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to treat the sequence of cubes of a single colour as a spline, then extrude a tube-shaped mesh over those spline points? [There's some past Q&A about constructing a tube around a sequence of points here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/137022/39518)

Comment: You may also want to consider forming a signed distance field from your points (or segments between consecutive points to avoid a string-of-pearls look), and using marching cubes to mesh an isosurface of that field. That would guarantee you get a water-tight mesh with no self-intersections.

Comment: I've had a look at signed distance fields here (https://jasmcole.com/2019/10/03/signed-distance-fields/) and it looks somewhat beyond my understanding.

A tube mesh would work definitely, I haven't managed to find any tutorials for doing that in Unity (it also seems to be called lofting).

Comment: Are there any suitable techniques for wrapping the entire shape?

Comment: @DMGregory jsut realised you probably won't see those comments unless I @ you!

Comment: I see them. The technique I'd recommend for wrapping the entire shape is marching cubes, as mentioned above, so I didn't see cause to repeat myself.